# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to solve this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined` in extjs?

I`m using dnd and put dnd code into layout browser

code :

```
// Generic fields array to use in both store defs.
var fields = [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'id'
}, {
    name: 'lab_name',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_name'
}, {
    name: 'lab_address1',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_address1'
}, {
    name: 'lab_address2',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_address2'
}, {
    name: 'lab_poskod',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_poskod'
}, {
    name: 'lab_bandar',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_bandar'
}, {
    name: 'lab_negeri',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_negeri'
}, {
    name: 'lab_tel',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_tel'
}, {
    name: 'lab_fax',
    type: 'string',
    mapping: 'lab_fax'
}];

// create the data store
var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: fields,
    autoLoad: true,
    url: '../industri/layouts/getLab.php'
});


// Column Model shortcut array
var cols = [{
    id: 'name',
    header: "Id",
    width: 10,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'id'
}, {
    id: 'name',
    header: "Laboratory Name",
    width: 200,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'lab_name'
}, {
    id: 'name',
    header: "Laboratory Name",
    width: 200,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'lab_address1'
}];
// declare the source Grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ddGroup: 'gridDDGroup',
    store: gridStore,
    columns: cols,
    enableDragDrop: true,
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'name',
    width: 325,
    margins: '0 2 0 0',
    region: 'west',
    title: 'Data Grid',
    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect: true
    })
});



// Declare the text fields.  This could have been done inline, is easier to read
// for folks learning :)
var textField1 = new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel: 'Laboratory Name',
    name: 'lab_name'
});


// Setup the form panel
var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    region: 'center',
    title: 'Generic Form Panel',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px; background-color: #DFE8F6',
    labelWidth: 100,
    margins: '0 0 0 3',
    width: 325,
    items: [textField1]
});


var displayPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    width: 650,
    height: 300,
    layout: 'border',
    padding: 5,
    items: [
        grid,
        formPanel
    ],
    bbar: [
        '->', // Fill
        {
            text: 'Reset Example',
            handler: function() {
                //refresh source grid
                gridStore.loadData();
                formPanel.getForm().reset();
            }
        }
    ]

});


// used to add records to the destination stores
var blankRecord = Ext.data.Record.create(fields);

/****
 * Setup Drop Targets
 ***/

// This will make sure we only drop to the view container
var formPanelDropTargetEl = formPanel.body.dom;

var formPanelDropTarget = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(formPanelDropTargetEl, {
    ddGroup: 'gridDDGroup',
    notifyEnter: function(ddSource, e, data) {

        //Add some flare to invite drop.
        formPanel.body.stopFx();
        formPanel.body.highlight();
    },
    notifyDrop: function(ddSource, e, data) {

        // Reference the record (single selection) for readability
        var selectedRecord = ddSource.dragData.selections[0];


        // Load the record into the form
        formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(selectedRecord);


        // Delete record from the grid.  not really required.
        ddSource.grid.store.remove(selectedRecord);

        return (true);
    }
});



var tabsNestedLayouts = {
    id: 'tabs-nested-layouts-panel',
    title: 'Industrial Effluent',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px;',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        border: false,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
        items: displayPanel
    }
};
```

Comment: It means you are trying to assign the property `dom` to a variable which doesn't have anything in it(i.e., **undefined**). That's all I can say to your little information. Give more information..(post the related code)

Comment: you haven't mentioned where exactly you getting this error. :)

Comment: error start after i put code "var blankRecord ...

Comment: I edited my answer after you pasted your code.

Comment: You can find the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917526/5881350

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extjs cannot read property error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916053/extjs-cannot-read-property-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you try and render a component to a `dom` element that isn't found (or `dom` ID that isn't found) you'll get that error. See the example below to reproduce the error - then comment out the bad renderTo and uncomment the `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` to resolve the issue.

see this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2evn)**

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    // Generic fields array to use in both store defs.
    var fields = [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'id'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_name',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_name'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_address1',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_address1'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_address2',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_address2'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_poskod',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_poskod'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_bandar',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_bandar'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_negeri',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_negeri'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_tel',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_tel'
    }, {
        name: 'lab_fax',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'lab_fax'
    }];

    // create the data store
    var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: fields,
        autoLoad: true,
        url: '../industri/layouts/getLab.php'
    });

    // Column Model shortcut array
    var cols = [{
        id: 'name',
        header: "Id",
        width: 10,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'id'
    }, {
        id: 'name',
        header: "Laboratory Name",
        width: 200,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'lab_name'
    }, {
        id: 'name',
        header: "Laboratory Name",
        width: 200,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'lab_address1'
    }];
    // declare the source Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        ddGroup: 'gridDDGroup',
        store: gridStore,
        columns: cols,
        enableDragDrop: true,
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'name',
        width: 325,
        margins: '0 2 0 0',
        region: 'west',
        title: 'Data Grid',
        selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
            singleSelect: true
        })
    });

    // Declare the text fields.  This could have been done inline, is easier to read
    // for folks learning :)
    var textField1 = new Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel: 'Laboratory Name',
        name: 'lab_name'
    });

    // Setup the form panel
    var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        region: 'center',
        title: 'Generic Form Panel',
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px; background-color: #DFE8F6',
        labelWidth: 100,
        margins: '0 0 0 3',
        width: 325,
        items: [textField1]
    });

    var displayPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        width: 650,
        height: 300,
        layout: 'border',

        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),

        padding: 5,

        items: [
            grid,
            formPanel
        ],
        bbar: [
            '->', // Fill
            {
                text: 'Reset Example',
                handler: function () {
                    //refresh source grid
                    //gridStore.loadData();
                    formPanel.getForm().reset();
                }
            }
        ]

    });

    // used to add records to the destination stores
    var blankRecord = Ext.data.Record.create(fields);

    /****
     * Setup Drop Targets
     ***/

    // This will make sure we only drop to the view container
    var formPanelDropTargetEl = formPanel.body.dom;

    var formPanelDropTarget = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(formPanelDropTargetEl, {
        ddGroup: 'gridDDGroup',
        notifyEnter: function (ddSource, e, data) {

            //Add some flare to invite drop.
            formPanel.body.stopFx();
            formPanel.body.highlight();
        },
        notifyDrop: function (ddSource, e, data) {

            // Reference the record (single selection) for readability
            var selectedRecord = ddSource.dragData.selections[0];

            // Load the record into the form
            formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(selectedRecord);

            // Delete record from the grid.  not really required.
            ddSource.grid.store.remove(selectedRecord);

            return (true);
        }
    });

    var tabsNestedLayouts = {
        id: 'tabs-nested-layouts-panel',
        title: 'Industrial Effluent',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:15px;',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {
            border: false,
            bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
            items: displayPanel
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It means that the object which you expect to have the `dom` attribute is undefined.

*EDIT:*
The error generates at this line:

```
formPanel.body.dom
```

It means that the `formPanel` is not rendered because you are trying to access its [`body`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-property-body) property. This property is **Available since: Ext 4.1.3**

Comment: i get this error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ,myb i`m using ext3

Comment: Than why are you trying to access properties that don't exist?

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing a similar error in code that executes for validation.  What I'm doing has nothing to do with directly accessing the DOM, however I'm still getting a similar condition.  The answer above is incomplete, the dom property is available on some ui elements in 3.x...

in earlier versions of Extjs (3.x) the property is mainBody.dom and not body.dom

directly from the source of hasRows() for grids in 3.4:

```
var fc = this.**mainBody.dom**.firstChild;
return fc && fc.nodeType == 1 && fc.className != 'x-grid-empty';
```

Comment: Here is the answer to the question above: In 3.4, the dom property is undefined until the item is actually rendered in the markup.