# Extjs cannot read property error

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, extjs, widget

[image]I made the following extjs code, but I get the error "cannot read property 'dom' of null" when I add the properties 'width' and 'height'
However the button is well resized and the table is working fine, but cause of this error my dropdown menu doesn't work properly.

Does anybody know how to solve it ?

```
<div id="tab-content">
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('BVCore.Grid', {
        id:'tab-content',
        renderTo: 'tab-content',
        stateId: 'tab-content',       
        store: Ext.create('BVCore.LocalStore', {
            fields: ['hostName', 'ip', 'serialNumber', 'model', 'role', 'status', 'siteName', 'installDate', 'linkedService'],
            proxy: {
                url:  '<spring:url value="/controller/search/json/deviceSearch.json" />'               
            },
        }),
        features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
        columns: [
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.hostname" />', dataIndex: 'hostName', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.ipaddress" />', dataIndex: 'ip', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.sn" />', dataIndex: 'serialNumber', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.model"/>', dataIndex: 'model', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.role" />', dataIndex: 'role', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.status" />', dataIndex: 'status', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.site" />', dataIndex: 'siteName', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.installDate" />', dataIndex: 'installDate', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {text: '<spring:message code="device.linkedService" />', dataIndex: 'linkedService', autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center'},
                  {autoSizeColumn: true, align: 'center', dataIndex: 'id',
                      renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                        var id = Ext.id();
                        Ext.defer(function () {
                            Ext.widget('button', {
                                renderTo: id,
                                text: 'Details',
                                width: 75,
                                height: 18,
                                handler: function () {
                                    window.location = "/netmg/controller/home/device/view/" + record.get('id');
                                }
                            });
                        }, 1);
                        return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
                      }
                  }
              ]
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine for me. Not sure why you are facing such problem.

Comment: I don't think it's because of the button. *renderTo: 'tab-content'* - Are you sure **'tab-content'** is defined? The error is coming from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error thanks to this post :

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246181-TypeError-el-is-null-el-el.dom-Ext.getDom(el)-in-ext-all-dev.js-(ligne-19839)

Answer (score 1):

It's not coming from the button config. 
The error is emanated from

> *renderTo: 'tab-content'*

In your code that the id of your grid is

> *'tab-content'*

And you are trying to render the same element to the element that you are creating. 
Make sure that you provide the right element *id* to which you want to render this grid. If not to any element then just assign

> `renderTo: Ext.getBody()`

Refer [renderTo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-renderTo) for more info.

Comment: I edited my description, tab-content is define. I want to put the grid into this div

Comment: i read the doc and it's says "Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager to render and manage its child items." but when I don't use renderTo the table disapear

Comment: I don't see no exceptions otherwise. Please make sure that the id for the grid is different from the div's id as well. And does "BVCore.Grid" have any custom changes? Can you share the code for that?

Comment: Check this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m0o . Check the index.html file. The app.js file is empty

Comment: And is it Browser specific?

Comment: No other div's have the same ID, the browser is chrome

Comment: I found the error the issue is on the line "renderTo: id," in the widget, when i replace id by Ext.getBody() the error disapear but the button is not well positionned. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: See, it was the renderTo :) . Button well not positioned as in? Can you update with screen shot?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my description ;)

Comment: Hmm... I don't seem to be able to reproduce that. In that fiddle that I created - I see that the buttons are rendered to the correct cells. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m0o

Comment: Ohh.. I just realized - changing "renderTo: id," is the reason why it's not rendered inside the cell. Try replacing it back to "renderTo: id" and increase the  milliseconds for the setTimeout to some 100-200.

Comment: it's the same behavior if I increase millisecond, I post the good answer found on another website ;) thank you for help :)